# Space tranlsation symmetry breaking

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, phase-transition, symmetry-breaking, many-body

If the given wave function of many particle system which is in liquid phase (say) is ,$$\psi( \vec{r_{1}},\vec{r_{2}},\vec{r_{3}},....\vec{r_{n}})$$

Probability density of finding the single particle is given by,

$$\rho(\vec{r_{1}})=\int d^{3} \vec{r_{2}} d^{3} \vec{r_{3}} d^{3} \vec{r_{4}}.....d^{3} \vec{r_{n}} \psi^{*}( \vec{r_{1}},\vec{r_{2}},\vec{r_{3}},....\vec{r_{n}})\psi( \vec{r_{1}},\vec{r_{2}},\vec{r_{3}},....\vec{r_{n}})$$

Two particle density is given by,$$\rho(\vec{r_{1}},\vec{r_{2}})=\int d^{3} \vec{r_{3}} d^{3} \vec{r_{4}}.....d^{3} \vec{r_{n}} \psi^{*}( \vec{r_{1}},\vec{r_{2}},\vec{r_{3}},....\vec{r_{n}})\psi( \vec{r_{1}},\vec{r_{2}},\vec{r_{3}},....\vec{r_{n}})$$

How does the second equation tells the information about whether space translation symmetry is broken unlike the first equation if the system is not really liquid but it is a crystal solid.
Can some one explain. This is explained in the page three of the following review article

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.03735.pdf